# Drawing a 3D cube and writing text next to it

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem. I have a dataframe `df`. This contains specifications like `length`, `width`, `height` and the `volume`.
I would like to calculate the `min`, `max` and `mean` values and display them graphically with a cube.
For this purpose, you can see below the following illustration of how I would like it to look. I would like to display a cube with texts next to it. In addition, there should be an additional line next to the `length`, `width`, `height`. How can I represent this cube graphically with the help of Matplotlib?

Dataframe

```py
   length  width  height  volume
0     1.5    1.5     1.5    0.15
1     0.4    0.8     0.6    0.85
2     4.3    8.5     3.5    1.15
3     3.3    4.5     2.4    0.02

         length     width    height    volume
mean   2.375000  3.825000  2.000000  0.542500
min    0.400000  0.800000  0.600000  0.020000
max    4.300000  8.500000  3.500000  1.150000
```

Code for dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "length": [1.5, 0.4, 4.3, 3.3],
    "width": [1.5, 0.8, 8.5, 4.5],
    "height": [1.5, 0.6, 3.5, 2.4],
    "volume": [0.15, 0.85, 1.15, 0.02],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What I want
[image]

Cube

```
# Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
  
  
# Create axis
axes = [5, 5, 5]
  
# Create Data
data = np.ones(axes, dtype=np.bool)
  
# Controll Tranperency
alpha = 0.9
  
# Control colour
colors = np.empty(axes + [4], dtype=np.float32)
  
colors[:] = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, alpha]  # red
  
# Plot figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
  
# Voxels is used to customizations of the
# sizes, positions and colors.
ax.voxels(data, facecolors=colors)
```

[image]